# Does variable get reassigned after each return or only when the recursion is finished

Tags: python, bubble-sort

In this bubble sort algorithm, when  `sort_array()` method is called, and when sorting is finished, the program continues to execute at line `return array`, and this line gets executed `n times` where `n` is the depth of the recursion depending on the input.
I have not used recursion a lot, so I am wondering does variable `sorted_list` gets reassigned `n times` (for the `new_list` 3 times) or just once when the recursion is over?

```
class Bubble:

    def __init__(self):
        self.swap_counter = 0

    def sort_array(self, array):
        for i, element in enumerate(array):
            if i < array.index(array[-1]):
                if element > array[i+1]:
                    temp_element = array[i+1]
                    array[i+1] = element
                    array[i] = temp_element
                    self.swap_counter += 1
        if self.swap_counter > 0:
            self.swap_counter = 0
            self.sort_array(array)

        return array


if __name__ == "__main__":
    new_list = [5, 1, 4, 2, 8]
    bubble = Bubble()
    sorted_list = bubble.sort_array(new_list)
```

Comment: It only gets assigned to once.

Comment: The array (list) is being *mutated*, so it is a bit disingenuous to return it as a value at all.. it also really muddles the question. Anyway, each recursive call has its *own* scope and independent local variables, even if they can _refer to_ (and thus be used to mutate) the same objects. Likewise, each recursive call can be exited only once.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I learned a lot